# Permuting a list of chars takes all my memory (Python)

Tags: python

I am building a dictionary of all the alpha and numbers. The problem with this code is "within matter of second consumes 100% of my memory". Do you think my implementation is bad?
Any Help is appreciated.

```
from timeit import Timer
from itertools import permutations
dictionary = []
small_alpha = map(chr, range(97,123))

lookup.append(small_alpha)

def test():
    for i in permutations(lookup, 10):
        dictionary.append(''.join(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

(Edited)
I am a well educated. No intent of hacking. This is realistically not possible even if I have 100 machines. No one can compute such a big number. Just was trying out if it is possible to some extent

Comment: You do realize that there are 922393263052800 possible permutations of those characters, right?

Comment: may be I will not all the computations. Just say 10 chars.

Comment: You'll need to rethink why you need to put them in a dictionary. It's very easy to iterate over permutions without actually storing them, and this is O(1) rather than O(n!).

Comment: What do you intend to do with the result? The only use for this kind of permutation that i can think of is for hacking.

Comment: I am a well educated. No intent of hacking. This is realistically not possible even if I have 100 machines. No one can compute such a big number. Just was trying out if it is possible to some extent.

Comment: I can't understand why you are surprised that this is using all of your memory

Answer (score 10):

There are 36!/(36-10)! = 922,393,263,052,800 permutations (~1 quadrillion) of 10 alphanumeric characters.  Of course this will take all your memory.

Assuming each string takes 32 bytes to store (8 bytes for the pointer, 8 bytes for the length, 16 bytes for the content*, on a 64-bit machine), this requires 26.2 [PiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebibyte) of memory.

There is no way to store all permutations in a normal machine. Please state what you actually want to do.

<sub>(*: Actually it takes much more than that, since there are also type information, and in Python 3.x a character costs 2 bytes for UTF-16, and the list itself also takes memory.)</sub>

---

Even with just the alphabets the number of permutations is still 19,275,223,968,000 (~20 trillion), and still takes 561 TiB of memory for 32 bytes per string.

Answer (score 2):

You need about 90077467 GB of memory to store the result data.

2 GB of memory costs $13 (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820146214), so you can fix this easily for the low, low price of $585,503,535.50.

Comment: (If you're curious, I made 1000000 copies of `['a']*10` as a memory estimate and extrapolated from there, but of course I make no warranties as to my math...)

Comment: (Actually, the OP's storing them as strings, not arrays, so that's not right.  Anyway, this solution is probably outside of his budget either way.)

Answer (score 2):

You're doing things pretty much right, using `itertools` to provide a generator rather than actually producing a list -- right up until you try to create a list. That list simply is going to use up all your memory because it is in fact huge. You should probably write it to a file rather than trying to make a list in memory, but you will need a *lot* of disk space.

Comment: According to other answers, an impractical amount of disk space. The only way you could handle that sort of sequence is to work with each thing as you produce it, and never try to keep the whole lot. And even then, expect to only be able to run through a small fraction of the total.

Comment: but that is computationally slower. And Dictionay is not reusable.

Comment: @Ringo In my view, algorithms try to achieve their goals in optimal *time* and *space*. In practice, however, these two goals contradict each other. One has got to give to accommodate the other.

Comment: He may have access to a petabyte of disk space. Probably not, but maybe the company he works for has a supercomputer cluster with an immense SAN or something.  :-) It is, anyhow, more likely that he'd have the disk than the RAM!

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use itertools, then use it all the way!

This is a perfect situation for a lazy generator--no need to actually store either the permutations or the data.

```
import itertools

small_alpha = itertools.imap(chr, range(97, 123))
numbers = itertools.imap(chr, range(48, 58))
lookup = itertools.chain(small_alpha, numbers)
d = (''.join(i) for i in itertools.permutations(lookup, 10))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    perms = list(itertools.islice(d,10))
    print(perms)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should utilize the cloud to solve this problem. using gnu parallel would provide you with additional resources to help you build your dictionary. http://unethicalblogger.com/posts/2010/11/gnuparallel_changed_my_life

Comment: yes, i did. i'm sorry if my silly answer was an inappropriate response to a silly question.

Comment: May it did not answer my question. But I got to know something about GNU Parallel. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly having variable called dictionary that is really a `list` is very confusing

Assuming you have enough memory, it would be much faster to use

```
dictionary = list(permutations(lookup, 10))
```

However since you don't have enough memory, this will just use up your memory even faster